# Can a client view the source code of a server-side python application

Tags: php, python, html

I am starting learning programming languages.

I struggled between PHP and Python.

I want to build a website and to parse strings from a form to a database.
But I just read, that you can't hide the source code of a python program.

So here is the question. 
I don't want others to see how my side does calculations. If the python program just works on the server side, will the clientside be able to see the python code if it is executed?

Sorry if this is a really newbe question.

Comment: No, clients will not be able to download your PHP or Python code, in either case. They will see your client-side HTML and JavaScript, though.

Comment: The client won't see the source code in either python or PHP, just the generated HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application runs on the server, the client can only see the data provided by the server.  So, if the server does not specifically share the source code with the client, the client won't be able to read it.

If you distribute an interpreted application to anyone then you are giving the source code to them and they can read it.  This applies to Python, Perl, Ruby, and many other languages.  Binaries from compiled languages, like C, C++, Java, are shared as binaries.  Instead of being human-readable content (source code) you share machine-readable compiled content.  Now, since it's machine readable, there are things called "decompilers" that will turn binaries into text, and even that will turn it into highly useful and highly readable text - readable source code.  This is even easier if debug is enabled when the compiler creates the binary

Answer (score 4):

On the client side, the Web browser can only see the output generated by the server-side code assuming the server is configured correctly. That output will be HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.—stuff a browser can consume. Browsers can't generally deal with Python so there would be no reason to send Python code to one. So the answer is yes; users of your Web site can't see the code running on the server unless you explicitly let them.

Answer (score 1):

Others are not able to see your server-side code from their browsers. They can only see HTML/CSS/(unencrypted)JavaScript, etc. Therefore, it doesn't matter which server-side language you use.

Answer (score 0):

It you are using php/python to generate the html (which seems to be the case here) then the only thing that the user would be able to see on the client side is the rendered html code(using browser's view source option) but they can't see you python/php logic/code if that's what you are worried about.